# Waiting for multiple async calls to complete?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have to call three different async methods from a WCF service. I have the following method that includes all three calls:

```
private async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync()
{
    CrimcaseServiceClient client = new CrimcaseServiceClient(
        new BasicHttpBinding(),
        new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.100/FooService/FooService.svc")
        );

    client.GetEventCompleted += OnGotEventResult;
    client.GetEventAsync(eventInfo);

    client.GetLocationsCompleted += OnGotLocationsResult;
    client.GetLocationsAsync();

    client.GetTypesCompleted += OnGotTypesResult;
    client.GetTypesAsync();
}
```

After all three calls have been completed, I need to populate some values. But, I seem to be running into problems with how I can wait for all three to finish up first.

I've tried doing this, using this call, but it is still not waiting for all of the calls to complete before going on to the next bit of code:

```
private void GrabData()
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () => { await CreateMultipleTasksAsync(); });
    task.Wait();
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as I'm lost at what to do at this point.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is the method signature for you async calls? Also, you say: *but it is still now waiting for all of the calls to complete before going on to the next bit of code* isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: That was a typo - sorry about that. I meant to say it is "not" waiting for all of the calls to complete before going on to the next bit of code. In looking at the generated calls, they are all setup as void. (I hope I'm understanding your question correctly)

Comment: I'm assuming the method signature is for the async method is `void` returning?

Comment: To be clear - this is [tag:c#], right? If so, please add a tag. If not, please add a different tag. It *looks* like C#, but could easily be some other language which may have *vastly* different notions of async and await.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> from a WCF service

I recommend that you rebuild your WCF client proxy, with asynchronous calls enabled. Currently, it is using [an older pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx), but if you regenerate it with a modern Visual Studio version, it should result in a [newer pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) that works better with `async`/`await`.

Then you can actually use `await` with your WCF calls directly:

```
private async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync()
{
  CrimcaseServiceClient client = new CrimcaseServiceClient(
    new BasicHttpBinding(),
    new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.100/FooService/FooService.svc")
    );

  // Start the three asynchronous calls.
  var getEventTask = client.GetEventAsync(eventInfo);
  var getLocationsTask = client.GetLocationsAsync();
  var getTypesTask = client.GetTypesAsync();

  // Asynchronously wait (await) for them all to complete.
  await Task.WhenAll(getEventTask, getLocationsTask, getTypesTask);

  // Retrieve the results of the calls.
  var event = await getEventTask;
  var locations = await getLocationsTask;
  var types = await getTypesTask;

  // TODO: place OnGotEventResult / OnGotLocationsResult / OnGotTypesResult logic here
}
```

When you call it, you should do so just with an `await`, not using `Task.Run` or `Task.Wait`:

```
await CreateMultipleTasksAsync();
// At this point, the results have been retrieved and processed.
```

Comment: Stephen Clearly - thank you so much for the details response. I had been using SvcUtil to generate the proxy. So, I removed the generated files, and added the Service Reference to my project directly through VS, but I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'. This is in Visual Studio 2013 working on a Xamarin PCL application. Am I just creating the proxy entirely wrong?

Comment: @SUCODev: I suspect it's the Xamarin app that's throwing it off. Try creating a regular PCL or .NET 4.5 dll and generate the service reference on that.

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary. Your solution seems to be exactly what I am looking for, but I'm not sure how to register and hookup OnGotEventResult / OnGotLocationsResult / OnGotTypesResult. Would you be willing to add that in your answer?

Comment: @user919426: My answer uses the TAP (`async`/`await`) approach, so it doesn't use those events at all.